# Encountered an error while attempting to update latest block

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, truffle

I'm new to blockchain and i was just trying to deploy a simple smart contract to ropsten test net. I've used the smart contract code from https://github.com/t4sk/solidity-multi-sig-wallet. Also i'm using the account provided by **truffle develop**

My truffle-config.js:

```
networks: {
development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
ropsten: {
    provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${infuraKey}`),
    network_id: 3,       // Ropsten's id
    gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
    confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
    timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
    skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    },
mocha: {
    timeout: 100000
  },
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.1",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
        optimizer: {
          enabled: false,
          runs: 200
        },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    }
  },
```

Im using solidity: 0.5.1

But when i try to deploy it using **truffle migrate --network ropsten** im getting the following two errors

1.

```
This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build:

Error: Cannot find module './uws_win32_x64_72.node'
Falling back to a NodeJS implementation; performance may be degraded.
```

2. 

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x673a9a02662595075c6f3aa4dc904d24203cb8e460a3e20a630869c5155cb78c
   > Blocks: 2            Seconds: 53
   > contract address:    0xde674E126884c8F7Ddd94B5013065596b81fEd6d
   > block number:        12075322
   > block timestamp:     1647065140
   > account:             0xC10352218af6Ccbb574Fd0912adcc9Ac59C22950
   > balance:             1.830076836873988898
   > gas used:            175087 (0x2abef)
   > gas price:           2.500000028 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.000437717504902436 ETH

   Pausing for 2 confirmations...

   -------------------------------

C:\Users\coolg\Desktop\hd_wallet\node_modules\request\request.js:848
          var e = new Error('ETIMEDOUT')
                  ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: ETIMEDOUT
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\coolg\Desktop\hd_wallet\node_modules\request\request.js:848:19)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (C:\Users\coolg\Desktop\hd_wallet\node_modules\eth-block-tracker\src\polling.js:51:24)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Also a transaction for the above smart contract address 0xde674E126884c8F7Ddd94B5013065596b81fEd6d is created on ropsten network.

**Edit 1:**
I've replaced the provider link with wss://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${infuraKey}` and the 2nd issue gets resolved but now it shows another error

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0xb72aef24e5fc16395f1dc221965c4e2036b4d72babbe829f244f958d302baee5
   > Blocks: 7            Seconds: 228
   > contract address:    0xb81478b107D5B08B0F9ce8d0E404701a3D2292a0
   > block number:        12076445
   > block timestamp:     1647090364
   > account:             0xC10352218af6Ccbb574Fd0912adcc9Ac59C22950
   > balance:             1.828763684345799891
   > gas used:            175087 (0x2abef)
   > gas price:           2.500000007 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.000437717501225609 ETH

   Pausing for 2 confirmations...

   -------------------------------
   > confirmation number: 3 (block: 12076452)
   ⠦ Saving migration to chain.
Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.


Error: Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!
```

It says the transaction might still be mined, so how will i know when my transaction gets mined? Also in the meantime can i call the fuctions/events of my smart contract that is deployed on the ropsten_eth https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xb81478b107d5b08b0f9ce8d0e404701a3d2292a0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here by mistake may be the address you are trying to reach. I searched for what the problem might be and found two threads where people have already described the problem and sort of found a solution. Most likely one of these options should help to solve the problem.

The first solution is [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3357#issuecomment-856841443). The idea is to replace `https` with `wss`. There should be something like this:

```js
testnet: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `wss://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${infuraKey}`),
  ...
}
```

Then I searched some more and found something like [this](https://community.infura.io/t/error-pollingblocktracker-encountered-an-error-while-attempting-to-update-latest-block/4215/2). The author of the post says that the problem could be due to **DNS** or **slow internet** and suggests adding two parameters to the config:

```js
testnet: {
  ...,
  networkCheckTimeout: 10000,
  timeoutBlocks: 200
}
```

Comment: i've added an edit to the question, please look into it.

Comment: @aj.24 I think there is most likely something wrong with sending the transaction. I found an option [here](https://community.infura.io/t/transaction-was-not-mined-within-750-seconds-please-make-sure-your-transaction-was-properly-sent-be-aware-that-it-might-still-be-mined/4240/2) , try to read and do what he recommends.

Comment: Are you sure it's networkCheckTimeoutnetworkCheckTimeout and not networkCheckTimeout?

Comment: You're right, corrected the answer